# Connections outlive SocketServer.TCPServer?

Tags: python, unix, networking

How can I make a TCP server properly close sockets?

I wrote a simple TCP server to echo some information back to client.  Now I would like to use it on localhost:8088 and stop it using `killall` and restart at any time as I'm working on the code.

However, I'm having trouble making it close all sockets and "free" the address, so when I quickly make a few tests, fix something in the code and then stop (Ctrl+C) and start the server again, I get `socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use`.

When I `sudo netstat -ntap`, I can still see few `127.0.0.1:8088` sockets in TIME_WAIT state.  So I have to wait until they "die out".

My test case:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import SocketServer

class MyEchoHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        # do something smart with the data, but for now, just say hello.
        self.reply = "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\nhello."
        self.request.send(self.reply)
        self.request.close()

def main():
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyEchoHandler)
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 8088
    main()
```

What am I doing wrong?  Shouldn't `self.request.close()` be enough?

I'm trying this on Debian with Python 2.7.3, although I need to support Squeeze with Python 2.6 as well.

Answer (score 5):

The TCP stack puts the port into timed-wait for awhile (something like 30 seconds to multiple minutes depending on your system). You can change that behavior with the SO_REUSEADDR socket option. The trick is that the option must be set before the port is bound.

If you have the raw socket, you can:

```
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

SocketServer lets you set the option globally with the allow_reuse_address attribute:

```
SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
```

Or you can do it when you create the server:

```
def main():
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyEchoHandler, False)
    server.allow_reuse_address = True
    server.server_bind()
    server.serve_forever()
```

Or even override the bind method:

```
class MyTCPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):

    def server_bind(self):
        self.allow_reuse_address = True
        super(MyTCPServer, self).server_bind()
```

Here are 3 solutions that worked for me on my Windows machine.

(1) set globally

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import SocketServer
import time

SocketServer.allow_reuse_address = True

class MyEchoHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        # do something smart with the data, but for now, just say hello.
        self.reply = "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n" + time.asctime()
        self.request.send(self.reply)
        self.request.close()

def main():
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyEchoHandler)
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 8088
    main()
```

(2) Set locally

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import SocketServer
import time

class MyEchoHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        # do something smart with the data, but for now, just say hello.
        self.reply = "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n" + time.asctime()
        self.request.send(self.reply)
        self.request.close()

def main():
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyEchoHandler, False)
    server.allow_reuse_address = True
    server.server_bind()
    server.server_activate()
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 8088
    main()
```

(3) Inherit

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import SocketServer
import time

class MyEchoHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        # do something smart with the data, but for now, just say hello.
        self.reply = "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n" + time.asctime()
        self.request.send(self.reply)
        self.request.close()

class MyTCPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):

    def server_bind(self):
        self.allow_reuse_address = True
        SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)

def main():
    server = MyTCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyEchoHandler)
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 8088
    main()
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of solution work: (not counting the raw socket solution) **(1)** setting allow_reuse_address globally did not change behavior;  **(2)** yells from socket.server_bind(): `socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`; when I remove the line, it's same as (1); **(3)** `TypeError: must be type, not classobj` from the super() clause

Comment: (1) works for me, (2) was a cut-and-paste error (should have included server.server_activate()), and (3) ... well, I didn't test that one. Turns out TCPServer is an old-style class and super doesn't work. Serves me right for trying to be clever. I'll edit the post with the scripts that worked for me.

Comment: (1) Still "mysteriously" does not work... (2) I did not notice that you need to set bind_and_activate to False--took the liberty and edited your code to make it stand out; now it works :) (3) works OK now

Comment: Turns out that the way is "works" is that while old sockets are *still* left in TIME_WAIT, **but** the LISTEN address can be reused, i.e. the server does not refuse to start.  (Eventually, it lives along with the old sockets still in TIME_WAIT).  So my check based on `netstat -ntap | grep 8088` does not really say everything here.

Comment: *"took the liberty and edited your code to make it stand out"* -- the edit was rejected as "too small", though :)

Answer (score -1):

You can call server.shutdown() but you have to do it from another thread 8-(   IMO this is weak area in Python's TCPServer.

Comment: That doesn't do anything about the TIME-WAIT state that is the topic of this question.